# Autifiltering in Excel with VBA using Textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

Hi I am new to VBA and I have pieced this together so far and I ended up getting it to work but not 100%.

I am trying to use multiple text boxes to auto-filter data. currently I am only using 2 for testing purposes but would like to eventually extend it to 4. Each one textbox currently filters but overrides tyhe other, where I want them to work together, so if I put a word in the first text box it will return all instances in that column that contain that word, and then wheen I add a word to the second it will filter those results even further,

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

If Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox2.Value & "*"
End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    filterTextboxes
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    filterTextboxes
End Sub

Private Sub filterTextboxes()    

    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 And Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Else
        If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If

        Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & _
            TextBox1.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & _
            TextBox2.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End If

End Sub
```